# What's the earliest possible ovulation day/ possibly pregnant

Tags: conceive-conception, ovulation, pregnancy-test

Been trying to conceive for over 2 years. Had my and hubby's hormones and swimmers checked, both normal. I do have a short-ish cycle, 24-26 days. I track every month and usually ovulate between days 8-10, which seems really early. My period this cycle was 2 days late, (if it was my period!?) lighter than normal, just took an ovulation test on day 4 and it was positive?? I don't want to get my hopes up but read that lh level changes could be another sign of pregnancy. Been taking preg tests all week, one right after the POS ovulation test and it was negative. I know I need to see my Dr but just going to be so anxious over the weekend and wanted some opinions.

Answer (score -1):

It is unlikely that the pregnancy test is wrong. Sometimes ovulation tests appear positive in pregnancy because LH is very structurally similar to a alpha-HCG, a subunit of HCG that is being secreted in pregnancy - and so ovulation tests also pick it up. However, a pregnancy test is more sensitive to HCG than an ovulation test, so a negative result on it is probably indicative of no pregnancy.

You could however test again in 3-4 days to make sure.

LH values can vary a bit during the cycle and have 'peaks' even when you're not ovulating.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].